# Execute function every X minutes

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm a little bit confused about how this should work. I have multiple objects saved in a XML file and those objects have a property for `TimeBetweenReposts` (like 10 minutes) and `TimesToRepost` (like 20 times).

Each object in part should trigger a function every `TimeBetweenReposts` minutes.

How can I do this?

Comment: You could construct a queue of all of the events in order of due time. Pick the first item from the queue, calculate how long you need to wait, wait, process the item, rinse, repeat. Or each object could maintain `NextTime` and `RemainingCount`. Just find the earliest `NextTime`, calculate the wait time, ... . If several items are due at the same time it doesn't really matter*. Just pick one and when you check for the next item due it will be due in zero time. (* Unless processing an item is time consuming. In that case you may want to hand them off to separate threads to process in parallel.)

Comment: I tried with threads, very bad idea. CPU at 99%

Comment: Did you have each thread use a timer or sleep (at no CPU cost) until it was time to do some work, or "spinwait" checking the time in a loop and consuming CPU as fast as possible?

Comment: No just tried to run 2 times the main function

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options, your most simple would be to create a separate thread which runs a function that looks something like this:

```
private void CheckTime()
{
    while (!exitCondition) //So you can cleanly kill the thread before exiting the program.
       {
           if (nextCheck < DateTime.Now)
           {
               DoAction();
               nextCheck = DateTime.Now + TimeBetweenReposts;
           }
           Thread.Sleep(1000); //Can be tweaked depending on how close to your time it has to be.
       }

}
```

Otherwise you could make entries in the system task scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Timer to do something every X seconds, or minutes or whatever you need.

You can implement a Timer like this :

```
public class XMLFilesManager
{
    Timer tm = null;

    public XMLFilesManager()
    {
        this.tm.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(XMLFilesManagerTimer_Elapsed);
        this.tm.AutoReset = true;
        this.tm = new Timer(60000);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        this.tm.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        this.tm.Stop();
    }

    protected void XMLFilesManagerTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
         this.tm.Stop();

         try
         {
             Execute();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             // LOG ERROR
         }
         finally
         {
             this.tm.Start();
         }
     }

     private void Execute()
     {
         // PUT YOUR BUSINESS LOGIC HERE
     }
}
```

Then, you can add a property to store the history of your execution, like :

```
// History of your object executions : object's identifier, last execution time and nb times you have execute the function for this object
List<Tuple<int,DateTime,int>> objectExecutionHistory = null;
```

And in the *execute* function, loop on your xml objects, and do what you have to do.